# If graph $G$ is connected and $\text{diam}(G)=k$ and $P$ and $Q$ are geodesic with length $k$, then $P$ and $Q$ have at least $1$ vertex in common.

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

> If graph $G$ is connected and $\text{diam}(G)=k$ and $P$ and $Q$ are geodesic with length $k$, then $P$ and $Q$ have at least $1$ vertex in common.

I start by assuming that this is false, therefore $P$ and $Q$ have no points in common.  But since $G$ is connected there's a path $A$ that connected any two points in $x \in P$ and $y \in Q$, respectively.

Then by choosing a point in $p \in P$ and $q \in Q$ such that the distance from $p, x$ and $q,y$ is maximum in $P$ and $Q$, we must have $d(p,x) + d(x,y) + d(y,q)$ be a path in $G$ that is larger than $k$, which is a contradiction.

**My question is:**  I feel like I'm missing something with this proof, did I assume something incorrectly here, particularly with the last step?

Comment: There is no contradiction with finding a path from $p$ to $q$ with the length longer than $k$. You need to show that if $P,Q$ are disjoint, then there exists two vertexes $x,y\in G$ such that the **shortest** path between $x,y$ is longer than $k$.

Comment: How would you show this?  I can't seem to figure a way to show that any path would be the shortest here.  I was figuring using the fact that if $d(x,y) = \text{diam}(G)$ then no geodesic $d(x,w)$ such that $w \neq y $ can contain $x$ since that contradicts the definition of diameter, but I'm not sure how I'd relate this.

Comment: The question is actually false I just realized.  Draw an equilateral triangle the put outwards facing squares on each of its edges.  The diameter of the graph is $3$ and you can you can connect points on the outward facing vertexes of the square of length $3$ that don't intersect.